# Having trouble with dynamically updating a BufferedImage

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, bufferedimage

I'm trying to render a dynamically changing image on a JPanel. I have tried many things and I simply do not get how to do it or what I'm doing wrong and I'm at the point of going insane. I'm new to swing and this is a small but essential part of my program which enables me to see what I'm doing.

The simple requirement is the picture rendered initially in the JPanel in the code mentioned below should update at each tick with random colors. I cannot get the image to update. Instead I get another square appearing in the middle of the image I'm trying to update and that small square dynamically changes. I do not know what I'm doing wrong. Please let me know how to rectify the code below so I could get the whole image to update.

Thank you.

The code is as follows

```
(MainTest.java)

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class MainTest extends JFrame {
static ImageEditor img ;
JPanel panel;
Timer to;

public MainTest()
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(265, 329);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    img =  new ImageEditor();
    panel = new ImageEditor();
    panel.setBounds(10, 11, 152, 151);
    panel.add(img);
    getContentPane().add(panel);

    JButton btnIterate = new JButton("Iterate");
    btnIterate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            ThirdClass t = new ThirdClass(img);
            to = new Timer(10,t);
            to.start();             
        }

    });
    btnIterate.setBounds(10, 230, 89, 23);
    getContentPane().add(btnIterate);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            MainTest frame = new MainTest();
            //frame.getContentPane().add(imgx);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}
}

(ImageEditor.java)
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ImageEditor extends JPanel {

private static BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, 1);  
public ImageEditor() {
    render();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (img == null)
        super.paintComponents(g);
    else
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
}


public void render() {

float cellWidth = 10;
float cellHeight = 10;

    int imgW = img.getWidth();
    int imgH = img.getHeight();
    float r, g, b;
    Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
    g2.setBackground(Color.black);
    g2.clearRect(0,0,imgW,imgH);
    for (int x=0; x<100; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y<100; y++) {
            r = (float)Math.random();
            g = (float)Math.random();
            b = (float)Math.random();
            g2.setColor(new Color(r,g,b));
            g2.fillRect((int)(x*cellWidth), (int)(y*cellHeight),
                        (int)cellWidth+1, (int)cellHeight+1);
        }
    }
    g2.setColor(Color.black);
    g2.dispose();
    repaint();
}

public BufferedImage getImage() {
    if (img == null)
        img = (BufferedImage)createImage(100, 100);

    return img;
}

public void setImage(BufferedImage bimg) {
    img = bimg;
}
}


(ThirdClass.java)
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class ThirdClass implements ActionListener {

static ImageEditor mock;

public ThirdClass(ImageEditor img)
{
    mock = img;
    Train();
}

public void Train()
{
    mock.render();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    Train();
}

    }
```

Comment: You're putting an `ImageEditor` in an `ImageEditor`. That's what you want?

Comment: You may want to try actually modifying the image itself, rather than replacing it each time, for instance, with `BufferedImage.getRaster().setPixel(x, y, rgbArray)`.

Comment: @jag426 I actually do not understand what you are referring to. But, if it is about the JPanel of type ImageEditor and the image itself I just want to put the buffered image in the JPanel and make it update.

Comment: @AJMansfield I tried this method but it gives me more trouble than solving them and the setPixel methods that's why I thought updating the whole image is easier.

Comment: Have you tried doing something simpler, like, without the button?

Comment: Also, you have a erroneous `}` right before the the `main` method.  As it stands currently, that method is not inside any class.

Comment: Nope that } correct otherwise it will not compile. No I have not tried without the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my initial post of the above question I have gone back to the basics and managed to answer my own question.

I am inserting the complete code below so another user having the same problem would not have to go through the same process over again.

My mistake was very trivial. However for people starting swing I think this might be helpful

```
(MainTest.java)
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class MainTest extends JFrame { 

ImageEditor img;
JPanel panel;
Timer t;

public MainTest()
{
    setSize(600,600);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    img = new ImageEditor();
    panel = img;
    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 510, 510);
    getContentPane().add(panel);

    JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");
    btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            test();
        }
    });
    btnStart.setBounds(0, 528, 89, 23);
    getContentPane().add(btnStart);
}

private void test() {
    Train tx = new Train(img);
    t = new Timer(100, tx);
    t.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            MainTest frame = new MainTest();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

  }

}

(ImageEditor.java)
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ImageEditor extends JPanel  {

private static BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(500, 500, 1);  

public ImageEditor() {
    setLayout(null);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (img == null)
        super.paintComponents(g);
    else
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
}

public void render() {

float cellWidth = 10;
float cellHeight = 10;

    int imgW = img.getWidth();
    int imgH = img.getHeight();
    float r, g, b;
    Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
    g2.setBackground(Color.black);
    g2.clearRect(0,0,imgW,imgH);
    for (int x=0; x<100; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y<100; y++) {
            r = (float)Math.random();
            g = (float)Math.random();
            b = (float)Math.random();
            g2.setColor(new Color(r,g,b));
            g2.fillRect((int)(x*cellWidth), (int)(y*cellHeight),
                        (int)cellWidth+1, (int)cellHeight+1);
        }
    }
    g2.setColor(Color.black);
    g2.dispose();
    repaint();
}

public BufferedImage getImage() {
    if (img == null)
        img = (BufferedImage)createImage(500, 500);

    return img;
}

public void setImage(BufferedImage bimg) {
    img = bimg;
}

}

(Train.java this class was named ThirdClass.java in my question)
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Train implements ActionListener {

ImageEditor temp;

Train(ImageEditor img)
{
    temp = img;
}

public void train()
{
    temp.render();  
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    train();
}

}
```

Thank you for all who commented and answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

From the code:

```
img =  new ImageEditor();
panel = new ImageEditor();
panel.setBounds(10, 11, 152, 151);
panel.add(img);
getContentPane().add(panel);
```

You are defining `img` as an `ImageEditor`, but you probably meant for it to be a `BufferedImage`.  You are then adding it to `panel`, which is another `ImageEditor` - but it is being added through the superclass method `JPanel.add`, when you probably meant to use the method you wrote, `ImageEditor.setImage()`.

EDIT: To summarize:

The tiny block of updating pixels you described is the `BufferedImage` (`img.img`), inside of your `ImageEditor img`, which is in turn inside of the `ImageEditor panel`, which is itself inside the applet's content pane.

- replace `static ImageEditor img` in the `MainTest` class with `BufferedImage img`
- replace `img = new ImageEditor` in `MainTest`'s no-args constructor with `img = new BufferedImage()`
- replace `panel.add(img)` in `MainTest`'s no-args constructor with `panel.setImage(img)`
- replace `static ImageEditor mock` in the `ThirdClass` class with `BufferedImage mock`
- replace the `ImageEditor img` argument in `ThirdClass`'s constructor with `BufferedImage img`
- replace any other stuff involving `img` to correctly handle it as a `BufferedImage`

One other thing, although this problem isn't itself the cause of any program malfunction, you should rename the `Train()` method in `ThirdClass` to something like `train()` so it matches proper java style.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Yes!!! I intended it to be the BufferedImage. I cannot check now since I just left office. I will check tomorrow.

Comment: I did the modification but now the updating small square is there but it is not the desired result. The code modified is as follows   img =  new ImageEditor();panel = new JPanel();

Comment: @Synex I have edited my answer to be more clear about exactly what changes I was proposing.

Comment: I checked your modifications but it does not work. The third bullet point will result in a compiler error since panel does not contain a setImage(BufferedImage) method. The fourth bullet point will result in a build break in the Train() method since there is no way invoking the render method of the ImageEditor.

Comment: @Synex The panel is still supposed to be an `ImageEditor`, which _does_ have a `setImage()` method.

Comment: Changed the declaration of panel to ImageEditor rather than JPanel. But the problem in the ThirdClass is still there

Comment: @Synex It's not my job to solve all your problems.  My original point is that the element chain is structured incorrectly.  At this stage, it is clear you don't really understand your program at all, so please just go back and rewrite it from scratch.

Comment: I know it is not your job to solve my problems. However, that is why I asked for help in this forum and I think that is why it is there for. As I told in my initial post I'm not a GURU of swing and if I'm I will be not asking this question. I only replied to the changes you proposed which clearly do not work. Thanks for making it your job to solve my problem for a day or so.